# Why is below 2 query generating different execution plan in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, execution-plan, order-by

Only difference in the below query is the order by column. The resultset of both query is same.
However, the 2nd query execution plan shows 'Using temporary; Using filesort' for ordering where as for 1st query it does not require filesort.

Apart from id I have index on c.table_b_id and c.some_indexed_id

```
SELECT * FROM TableA a 
inner join TableB b on a.id = b.id 
inner join TableC c on c.table_b_id = b.id
where c.some_indexed_id = 1
order by c.table_b_id asc;



SELECT * FROM TableA a 
inner join TableB b on a.id = b.id 
inner join TableC c on c.table_b_id = b.id
where c.indexed_id = 1
order by b.id asc;
```

Comment: 1st query may use index whereas 2nd query cannot. PS. The execution plans comparing makes sense for equivalent queries only.

Comment: You added [tag:execution-plan], but where are the actual plans? Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Answer (score 0):

The explain depends on which column you using in `WHERE` clause, the column which are large in size that which doesn't fit in `SORT BUFFER` requires `filesort` for sorting purpose. And other point is `b.id` may be primary key which is sorted by default, So it doesn't requires to do sorting & where `c.table_b_id` requires sorting.